# SQL Server : identify first row value appears in column and insert into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I have the following table structure:

```
Id     | TransNbr | Type |
-------+----------+------+
1235   | 220      | A    |
1236   | 221      | A    |
1237   | 220      | A    |
1238   | 220      | B    |
1239   | 221      | B    |
```

I need to add a new column to this table that would indicate if this was the first `TransNbr` of type `A`.

I was able to get the following `SELECT` query to work... but I'm unsure how to now add the new populate `FirstTime` column to the `INVOICE` table:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE 
       WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TransNbr ORDER BY Id)) = 1 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
    END FirstTime
FROM INVOICE
WHERE Type = 'A'
```

Comment: Your code does not seem related to "indicate if this was the first TransNbr of Type A".  What rows do you want it to identify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to create the firsttime field:

```
ALTER TABLE INVOICE
ADD firsttime BIT NULL;--or tinyint
```

This should update the newly-minted column accordingly.

```
UPDATE invoice
SETfirsttime = a.firsttime
FROM invoice 
INNER JOIN  
(
SELECT  id, 
    CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TransNbr ORDER BY 
    Id))=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FirstTime
FROM INVOICE 
WHERE Type = 'A')a 
ON invoice.id = a.id
```

Tested with your sample data, and it looks good.

Comment: This worked great!  Thanks for helping me figure this out!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to update a field on the row with id 1235, then you would do:

```
with toupdate as (
      select i.*, row_number() over (partition by type order by id) as seqnum
      from invoice
      where type = 'A'
     )
update toupdate
    set FirstTime = 1;
```

You can adjust the logic in the CTE if this doesn't do what you really want.

If you don't have the `FirstTime` flag, you can do:

```
alter table invoice add FirstTime tinyint default 0;
```

Comment: your logic doesn't do the same as the `SELECT` which the OP provided. All rows with the type of A will get a 1, and that includes two rows with the same transnbr. Additionally, OP has the partition done on the transnbr, whereas you have it on the type field.

Comment: @Eli . . . It is a little hard to tell what the OP really wants.  I was going by the description:  "I need to add a new field to this table that would indicate if this was the first TransNbr of Type A."  The OP would choose two *different* `TransNbr`s, and that definitely does not seem like the intention.